# ODBC SQL query from a C++ application suddenly shows up argument type incompatible

Tags: c++, sql, odbc

I'm learning how C++ queries from Microsoft SQL server. Initially, I successfully exacuted the code. However, when I created **another new project **and copied that code into it, an issue occurs. An error showed the argument of type "SQLCHAR" is incompatible with parameter of type "SQLWCHAR". The code is as follow below:

```
SQLCHAR SQLState[1024];
SQLCHAR message[1024];
if (SQL_SUCCESS == SQLGetDiagRec(handleType, handle, 1, SQLState, NULL, message, 1024, NULL))
// Returns the current values of multiple fields of a diagnostic record that contains error, warning, and status information
cout << "SQL driver message: " << message << "\\nSQL state: " << SQLState << "." << endl;
```

I have no idea which configure I made a mistake in ?

I've changed the datatype, SQLCHAR, into SQLWCHAR, but that will make connection fail.

Comment: All of the WinAPI is conditional on `UNICODE` being defined (usually in the project settings).  If `UNICODE` is defined most of the WinAPI function calls and a lot of the type default to the wide character set.  That said can you also provide the full error message as the above code looks to be ok.

Comment: `when I created **another new project **` -- What character set type was the old project?  Was it MultiByte Character Set (MBCS) or was it Unicode?  What character set type is used in the new project?  Is it MBCS or Unicode?  Now do both projects use the same character set  type?  You find the Character Set setting in your project `Properties->General->Character Set`